# Kotlin coroutine for executing external process

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The traditional approach in Java to execute an external process is to start a new `Process`, start two threads to consume its `inputStream` and `errorStream` and then call its blocking `Process.waitFor()` to wait till the external command has exited.

How can this be done in a (almost) non-blocking style with Kotlin coroutines?

I tried it this way. Do you have any suggestions to improve it?

(How to asynchronously read the streams, also call `ProcessBuilder.start()` in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`, are there too many calls to Dispatchers.IO, ...?)

```
    suspend fun executeCommand(commandArgs: List<String>): ExecuteCommandResult {
        try {
            val process = ProcessBuilder(commandArgs).start()

            val outputStream = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { readStream(process.inputStream) }
            val errorStream = GlobalScope.async(Dispatchers.IO) { readStream(process.errorStream) }

            val exitCode = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                process.waitFor()
            }

            return ExecuteCommandResult(exitCode, outputStream.await(), errorStream.await())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return ExecuteCommandResult(-1, "", e.localizedMessage)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun readStream(inputStream: InputStream): String {
        val readLines = mutableListOf<String>()

        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                inputStream.bufferedReader().use { reader ->
                    var line: String?

                    do {
                        line = reader.readLine()

                        if (line != null) {
                            readLines.add(line)
                        }
                    } while (line != null)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // ..
            }
        }

        return readLines.joinToString(System.lineSeparator())
    }
```

Comment: What's the point of all this since you'll still occupy the same number of threads with blocking operations? At least you could replace `waitFor` with a loop `while (process.isAlive() delay(100)`. This wouldn't occupy any thread.

Comment: That's why I pose the question, to improve the code ;).

Do you also have another suggestion to improve the stream reading?

Comment: There is no getting around blocking APIs. Stream reading is blocking and it will stay that way with coroutines. `InputStream` has the `available()` method that could theoretically allow you to avoid blocking, but I think it only reports the data left in the Java-side buffer. Nothing gets you around native blocking calls.

Answer (score 1):

I just bumped into this 3 year old question and thought about making improvements to this code. I think that this code does already the most optimized approach because we can't really do anything when it comes to blocking operations from the source, but I think you can save some context switching and improve the code like this:

```
suspend fun executeCommand(commandArgs: List<String>): ProcessResult = withContext(
    Dispatchers.IO
) {
    runCatching {
        val process = ProcessBuilder(commandArgs).start()
        val outputStream = async {
            println("Context for output stream -> $coroutineContext -> Thread -> ${Thread.currentThread()}")
            readStream(process.inputStream) }
        val errorStream = async {
            println("Context for error stream -> $coroutineContext -> Thread -> ${Thread.currentThread()}")
            readStream(process.errorStream)
        }
        println("Context for exit code -> $coroutineContext -> Thread -> ${Thread.currentThread()}")
        val exitCode =  process.waitFor()
        ProcessResult(
            exitCode = exitCode,
            message = outputStream.await(),
            errorMessage = errorStream.await()
        )
    }.onFailure{
        ProcessResult(
            exitCode = -1,
            message = "",
            errorMessage = it.localizedMessage
        )
    }.getOrThrow()
}

private fun readStream(inputStream: InputStream) =
    inputStream.bufferedReader().use { reader -> reader.readText() }

data class ProcessResult(val exitCode: Int, val message: String, val errorMessage: String)
```

Just ignore the prinln. I leave it there if you want to see it clearly on which context the coroutines are running. It makes it also more visible to see that they share the same scope and they run on different threads. But they should be removed when going to production code.